# adding TableView Rows with AlertAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uialertaction

Maybe somebody can help me. I want to add a new Table View Row to a `tableView`. If you press the plus button on the top right corner an alert pops up and you can enter some text and this Text is getting added to the table.

When I am pressing the plus button I am always getting an error

> (SIGABRT :'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
>   *** First throw call stack:)

I dont get it.

```
@property NSMutableArray *objects;
@property NSString *shopping;


- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
if (!self.objects) {
    self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
//call an alert Action
UIAlertController *textEntry = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"new Item" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[textEntry addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField){
    textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString ( @"zb. pickle", @"cde");

}];
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
    UITextField *enteredText = textEntry.textFields.firstObject;
    _shopping = enteredText.text;



}];
[textEingabe addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:textEingabe animated:YES completion:nil];

[_objects insertObject:_shopping atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
//Not quite sure if this is the right code
cell.textLabel.text = [_objects objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Please check that.

```
 [_objects insertObject:_shopping atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

You are adding object before you are done with alert view input. So insert object inside alertview compltion.

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
    if (!self.objects) {
        self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    //call an alert Action
    UIAlertController *textEntry = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"new Item" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [textEntry addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField){
        textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString ( @"zb. pickle", @"cde");

    }];
    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        UITextField *enteredText = textEntry.textFields.firstObject;
        _shopping = enteredText.text;

      [_objects insertObject:_shopping atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }];
    [textEingabe addAction:okAction];
    [self presentViewController:textEingabe animated:YES completion:nil];



    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //Not quite sure if this is the right code
    cell.textLabel.text = [_objects objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    return cell;
```

Comment: This is not a full answer to the question. Please explain what the problem was and how you fixed it rather than posting working code

Comment: @podoi17 Welcome bro :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting nil to `_objects`

it should be something like this:

```
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
    UITextField *enteredText = textEntry.textFields.firstObject;
   _shopping = enteredText.text;
   [_objects insertObject:_shopping atIndex:0]; // insert object here
}];

[textEingabe addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:textEingabe animated:YES completion:nil];
```

unless you have a default value for `_shopping`?.

like:

```
_shopping = @"default";
<some code>
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
UITextField *enteredText = textEntry.textFields.firstObject;
_shopping = enteredText.text;
}];

[textEingabe addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:textEingabe animated:YES completion:nil];
[_objects insertObject:_shopping atIndex:0]; // this way _shopping will never be nil.
```